# How can I reset my C: without losing users

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd

I have had my computer for like a decade now and while most parts have been renewed, not my C: SSD. Since I am fairly new to being 'good' with computers I did not follow any logic, such as deleting programs instead of uninstalling them, having no Drive structure and installing stuff wherever and everything being a mess. Using WinDirStat, about 30/40% of my drive is installers.

I have 2 more drives with similiar problems but cleaning that will be easy, i will just create a list of all programs, backup all data such as repositories, pictures etc and then wipe, reinstall everything and fixed it is. The issue I have and help I need here is formatting my C: to get rid of all dead things that are neither used nor referenced just junking up the drive, and then reinstalling windows and somehow importing the old users. I will for the time being just create an image of my C: so that I can reclaim any data i accidentally lost.

Or is there another way to do this? I have my other drives for a reason so if there is a way to delete all non-user and OS data from a drive that'd be good. I guess the registry would still contain dead things, but I would at least not have to reinstall windows, which, never is fun since you needed internet to do so. But just deleting my 2 programs folder doesn't sound like a good idea because then I'll still have all the installers which I don't want to delete because I fear something horrible would happen from it.

Whatever the suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to easily transfer programs and user data between Windows installs. You will need to manually reinstall the programs and manually transfer documents, photos, etc. if you want to avoid some serious issues. My suggestion to you would be to move your documents and photos to a flash drive or cloud storage and then format the drive and reinstall Windows, then just put your personal data on the new install and reinstall the programs you need manually.

Comment: @SamForbis damnit, guess that is what i will do. thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "installers" and in which folder(s) are they found?

Comment: @harrymc Windows/Installer/<Files> is 41GB. I am no hardware/IT/pc architecture nerd all I do is code so idk if i am misunderstanding the purpose of this folder, but I have no clue why it is 41GB and full of .msp and .msi files. I once read that program installers are stored in that folder and that many people have it bloated like this but maybe I misremember. Since i will wipe C soon anyway, is it safe to delete it now to temporarily clean up space?

Comment: Mine are less than 7 GB. You shouldn't cleanup manually files in `C:\Windows`. Have you tried [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17421/windows-free-up-drive-space#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-8)? You could also try out [PatchCleaner](https://www.homedev.com.au/Free/PatchCleaner). As long as you have a good backup ...

Comment: @harrymc already backuped, will try it. Thanks!

Comment: In the future, if you do a Windows 10 Repair Install (Media Creation Link) you do not have to lose anything if the errors can be repaired this way (most errors can be repaired this way)